# MYSQL PHP Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, prepared-statement

So I haven't really worked with PHP Sessions much and trying to learn. Despite trying to look online I'm a bit stuck. So I have a login page which works and lets people login but when they get to the welcome page I can't display anything other than the id, username or password (if I really wished)

So here's the code for the login page~:

```
 <?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password FROM tourn_admins WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            $_SESSION["firstname"] = $firstname;


                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Control Panel | Tournament | SymplieCloud</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">

                    </span>
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-48">
                        <img src="" width="40%" height="auto" class="login-logo">
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>" data-validate = "">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <span class="btn-show-pass">
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding: 20px;">
                        <span><?php echo $username_err; echo $password_err; ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-115">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Having difficulties?
                        </span>

                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Contact Us
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then Heres the code for the welcome page:

```
    <?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <h1><?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"]; ?><b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Your Password</a>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to be able to display all the rows data. So I have ID, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Phone, Username, Password and Timestamp. I just want to be able to display them through the session like `$_SESSION["firstname"];` As you may be able to see I have tried to have a go but is unsuccesfull. Again, am learning here so if you see anything which could be better, any critisim would be apprciated :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: so the part in the "// Store data in session variables" is not working?

Comment: In general, you should not provide different errors for "incorrect password" and "email not found." By doing so, you allow attackers to determine which accounts are valid in your system.

Comment: Oh, I see so just have it so instead of saying username error, password error just has one general error? @miken32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not binding enough results to your prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password FROM tourn_admins WHERE username = ?";
```

Your statement fetches 7 columns, but your `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` call only has 3 variables:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
```

You need to add variables for all the columns you are reading in the query i.e.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $username, $hashed_password);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick, Greatly Appreciated - Just a tip for all once you make changes to your index file you have to logout and log back in to make it work!!!